# can't create zombie process in linux

Tags: c, linux, bash, process, zombie-process

Well I have weird problem.
I can't create a zombie process in my project, but I can do this in other file.
There's simple instructions:

```
int main()
{
    if(fork()==0)
        printf("Some instructions\n");
    else
    {
        sleep(10);
        wait(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That simple code create a zombie process for 10 seconds. I'm checking and it actually exists.

But if I copy this code to my program (my own shell), everything executing like before BUT zombie process doesn't exist at all. I don't know what's the difference. It's same code.

Is there a more information I should know about that?
Is there a other way to create zombie in simple way?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to create a zombie?

Comment: That program is straightforward and dead simple. What does your larger program look like when you copy this code into it?

Comment: any chance you've got a SIGCHLD handler in that larger project ? or otherwise modified the default one ?

Comment: This makes no sense at all as it is. I don't see a point to creating a process only for it to become defunct right away. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You don't create zombies if you ignore the SIGCHLD signal or set the SA_NOCLDWAIT flag when installing the handler for SIGCHLD http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sigaction.html

Comment: Well I need to create zombies, that's a fact.
I dont have any SIGCHLD handler.

Answer (score 4):

Try this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

import subprocess
import time
import threading

# Create 100 subprocesses 

proc = {}
for i in xrange(0,1000):
        proc[i] = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'])

# create zombies from this processes, observe one minute zombies
time.sleep(60)

# Zombies dead
proc.communicate()

time.sleep(5)
```

Thereafter check zombies:

```
# ps -A | grep defunc
14711 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14713 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14716 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
.... 
14740 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14741 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14742 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14743 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14746 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14749 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
....
14805 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
14806 pts/49   00:00:00 ls <defunct>
```

Or C:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main ()
{ 
  pid_t child_pid;

  child_pid = fork ();
  if (child_pid > 0) {
    sleep (60);
  }
  else {
    exit (0);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Should work like a charm, like a crystal clear pure [Haitian Vodou](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haitian_Vodou).