# How do I create multiple zombies in a Linux kernel?

Tags: c, zombie-process

I am writing a project for class that finds zombies and reaps them in a Linux kernel.

I have found code that will create a single zombie, which gets reaped after a wait(), but my program must reap many, on the order of 1000.

I am very new to kernel manipulation/multi-threading and the resources I have found online dealing with zombies are either too technical, or ambiguous.

This is the code I am using:

```
      pid_t child_pid;

      child_pid = fork ();
      if (child_pid > 0) {
          sleep (60);
      } else {
          exit (0);
      }
```

Once again, my question is: How should I go about creating multiple zombies, for my program to reap?

Much thanks -Jared

Comment: Well you managed to create one. Repeat what you just did before you exit and you'll get two. Do that in a loop and you'll get as many as you want.

Comment: don't you have some sort of a do_exit method? This should mark your process for cleanup, and be called whenever all the process's threads exit

Comment: I remember [another question where the OP tried to create zombie processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13647519/cant-create-zombie-process-in-linux). Like I said on the other question, what's the point? What's with people who want to create zombie processes?

Comment: @Mat That doesn't quite work. I put lines 3-8 in a for loop, but it only creates one at a time because of sleep. I tried taking out the sleep and the program exits and reaps the zombies.

Comment: @netcoder This is for a project for school where I have to write a memory manager that reaps zombies. I need to create zombies to reap them. lol

Comment: @Jared: well, you didn't do what I said you should. Try creating two zombies first (without a loop), then three, then see the pattern?

Comment: Multiple zombies? Dude, you're confusing Valentine's Day with Halloween!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A zombie is no more than one terminated process who got a parent that didn't read his exit status (in a nutshell: parent didn't call `wait()` after the child exit) and keep memory and resources busy.

To achieve what you need just fork a lot of processes (use a loop for example) and never call `wait()`

Comment: Got it, the fork statement is the only line that should be included in the loop. Thank you ^.^